# Remove singular points

Tags: taylor-expansion, bessel-functions, singularity

I'm developing a tool in Matlab and since it doesn't now how manage singularities, I need to correct these two equations:

$A(\theta,\phi)=\frac{1+cos\theta}{2}\frac{J_0(kasin\theta)}{2.405^2-(kasin\theta)^2}(cos\phi+sin\phi)$
$B(\theta,\phi)=\frac{1+cos\theta}{2}\frac{J_0(kasin\theta)}{2.405^2-(kasin\theta)^2}(-sin\phi+cos\phi)$

where $J_0$ is the Bessel function of the first kind order 0 and I need to eliminate whatever singularity. The first one that I saw is the first fraction

$\frac{1+cos\theta}{2}\simeq 1-\frac{\theta^2}{2}$
then for the second one I used Taylor expansion again and I found that

$\frac{J_0(kasin\theta)}{2.405^2-(kasin\theta)^2}=\frac{J_0(x)}{x_0^2-x^2}\simeq -\frac{J_0'(x_0)}{x+x_0}$

but I have still some issue somewhere because the [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhMrE.png) that I'm trying to obtain has a strange behaviour away from the origin. I think that what I am doing so far is correct since I don't have singularity in (0,0), but stil...
If you confirm me that there are no any other singularity, than I'm probably doing something wrong in my code to manage these points.
For the first one I use

```
if abs(1-cos(theta))<eps
do thing
else
(1+cos(theta))/2
```

Same approach for the other one. eps is a very small constant variable (0.01)

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"?  What singularities are you trying to remove?  There is no singularity to remove at $\theta = 0$.  On the other hand, assuming your $2.405$ isn't really $2.405$ but rather the location of the first zero of $J_0$, there are removable singularities at $\pm$ that value of $k a \sin(\theta)$.

Comment: I meant that I removed the singularity for $\theta=0$ but then looking at that graph, it looks like that there's another singularity but I cannot figure which is it. $2.405$ is the first zero ($2.4058$) I lost a number but it is not the point. Inside my code is exactly 2.4058, but still that graph has that kind of behaviour for y=-0.5, y=0.5. See the link in "graph" which make me think that there is another singularity but I don't know where.

Comment: What "singularity for $\theta=0$"?  I repeat, there is no singularity there.

Comment: I'm sorry I noticed now. I didn't mean the singularity for $\theta=0$. The singularity that I've corrected is the one when $2.405^2-(kasin\theta)^2=0$ and then I thought that the other problem would have been the one for $1+cos\theta=0$ but still I have that behaviour in the graph.

Answer (score 1):

If $x_0$ is a zero of $J_0$, then near $x=x_0$ you have
$$ \frac{J_0(x)}{x - x_0} = J_0'(x_0) + \frac{x-x_0}{2} J_0''(x_0) + \frac{(x-x_0)^2}{6} J_0'''(x_0) + \ldots $$
Use as many terms as you need to get sufficient accuracy.